# How do I cd to the closest parent folder that has a .git folder with bash?

Tags: git, bash, cd

When working on projects that are version controlled I often end up in a nested folder. Using `cd ../../` gets a bit cumbersome, so I was wondering if there is a way to define an alias in bash that cd's to the parent until it reaches a folder with a `.git` folder, or it reaches `~`.

So let's say that

- `~/my-project` is a git repository
- my cwd is `~/my-project/deeply/nested/folder/structure`
- I run the command and am cd'ed to `~/my-project`

What command could do this? Would I need a bash function?

Comment: If you're using a shell on Unix, you might find good answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, you can make a bash function that uses it.

```
gr() {
    cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
}
```

I also have in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    root = rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Which makes this command a little more reasonable looking.

Comment: Distilled: paste into your `.bash_aliases`: `alias gr='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"'`

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer you already have is good (and possibly more efficient) but a basic way of achieving this would be to use a loop:

```
until [ -d .git ]; do cd ..; done
```

That is, move into the parent directory until the directory `.git` exists.

To protect against an infinite loop if you run the command from outside of a git repo, you could add a basic check:

```
until [ -d .git ] || [ "$PWD" = "$p" ]; do p=$PWD; cd ..; done
```

I'm not sure how portable it is, but on my system I have a variable `$OLDPWD` which can be used instead:

```
until [ -d .git ] || [ "$PWD" = "$OLDPWD" ]; do cd ..; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Again, already answered, but I have a script as follows that does essentially that:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
[[ ! ${filename} ]] && echo "no filename" && exit -1
path=$(pwd)
while [[ "${path}" != "" && ! -e ${path}/${filename} ]]; do
   path=${path%/*}
done
[[ "${path}" == "" ]] && exit -1;
cd ${path}
```

where you would do `findup .git` (which in turn could be turned into an alias)

Comment: I would change the first test to either `! [ "$filename" ]`, or if you're going for bash-only, then `[[ ! $filename ]]`. You could also drop the `!` and use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: This is how to do the same thing in Fish: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762098/9041